# How to extract SAP ERP data for a particular year

Tags: sap-erp, jco, sapjco3

I am trying to extract `BSEG` table data from SAP ERP system. I want to set a filter on field `GJAHR` for year 2018 so that data for that particular year will be extracted. Below is the code snippet:

```
if(fields != null){
   JCoTable table = function.getTableParameterList().getTable("FIELDS");
   for (String field : fields) {
    table.appendRow();
    table.setValue("FIELDNAME", field);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the function module RFC_READ_TABLE, there is a table parameter called **OPTIONS**, which has one column named **TEXT**. Here the condition for GJAHR = 2018:

```
JCoTable options = function.getTableParameterList().getTable("OPTIONS");
options.appendRow();
options.setValue("TEXT", "GJAHR EQ 2018");
```